# How do I print a view table?

Tags: 7

I am using Drupal 7 with the Print module installed.
I used this module to print nodes, but how can I print a view table?

Is there a module that I can use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing views table](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27283/printing-views-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're familiar with the Print module, you could simply [embed](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) the view you're displaying into a normal node and use Print to print the page. I didn't try this but I see no reason it wouldn't work.

In your node's tpl.php, do something like this :

```
print views_embed_view('your_view', 'the_display_you_want');
```

Answer (score 2):

Most people just use a stylesheet to exclude layout for printing. it does not rely on any particular module.

The idea is simple, you include a stylesheet in your theme which removes the layout from your site, typically by using `style:display:none;` etc. You also size the font and remove images where possible to save ink.

You can read a really good tutorial here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/